# gRPC JAVA should I choose server side streaming or bidirectional streaming

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

My client application constantly handle requests from users.Also, I have a server application that only handles requests from client application and do some heavy work, and tells my client application the result.

In my client application, for each request, it needs to send the request to the server application, and the server may respond with multiple results.

My question is, in my case, should i use server side streaming for each request, or bidirectional streaming for all requests. Pros and Cons.

For server side streaming，it means I have to call stub.method() for each request, is it heavy? Since it runs in production environment, I hope for the best performance。

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description it looks like server side streaming is your best option. I am assuming each request from the client application consists of a message (instead of an unbounded stream of messages) but the response consists of a stream of messages - hence server side streaming.

Bidirectional streaming is not a good fit for the following reasons:

- you will need to define your request stream to consist of multiple requests within the stream
- you will similarly need to define the response stream to correlate set of response messages to a request message in the request stream
- you will do all of this in a long lived bidi RPC for apparently no benefit and handle restarting the RPC and resend failed request messages

The overhead of calling stub.method() for each client request is not heavy for the benefit you get.